# How to get values between two numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

["10","13"] is the array, need to find the values between them and flatten the array with the values -> ["10","11","12","13"].

The first array above (["10", "13"]) is in a list of arrays.

```
const OriginalData = {
   Red:{
      Name:"L",
      List:[
         ["1", "5"],
         ["2", "5"],
         ["7", "9" ],
      ]
   },
   Blue:{
      Name:"BL",
      List:[
         ["1", "5"],
         ["7", "9" ],
         ["10", "13" ],
         ["15", "20"]
      ]
   },
   Black:{
      List:[
         ["Random"],
         "Random2"
      ]
   }
}
```

Then finally Object must look like,

```
{
   Level:{
      Name:"L",
      List:[
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9
      ]
   },
   Basement:{
      Name:"BL",
      List:[
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
     ] 
   },
   Custom:{
      List:[
         "Random",
         "Random2"
      ]
   }
}
```

What It should do:
Take the first object, inside List there are set of ranges, the values between those ranges should be found a flatten without duplicates.
Finding the values between is only for "Red", and "Blue", In "Black" key only flatten is needed.

I tried,

**Code:**

```
  const submitData = () => {
    let obj = originalData;
    let flattenedArray = [].concat.apply([], originalData.Red.List);
    let uniqueArray = flattenedArray.filter(
      (v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i
    );
    obj = {
      ...originalData,
      Red: {
        ...originalData.Red,
        List: uniqueArray,
      },
    };
    console.log(obj);
  };
```

The above code flattens the array but will not find between the numbers and it only worked for key "Red"

Comment: Once you flatten the list, use min and max to get your full range of the array. Then use those conditions to create a new array with a simple loop. I would also split up your code to get that range from another function, this way you can reuse it and pass the list as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example to create a range:

```js
let example = ["10","13"];
let min = Math.min(...example);
let max = Math.max(...example);
let result = [];

for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  result.push(i);
}

console.log(min, max, result)
```

Comment: this works only for a single array. Mine is List of arrays

Comment: Sorry, as I said in my comments this is just the function to get the range. The rest of your code seems to work. I thought you already had achieved a flattened list. (Like you said in your first sentence)

Comment: Yeah, but the looping through the list isn't working properly. Would you mind posting the entire code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it with a simple logic and will work for random numbers as well.

Try this (Descriptive comments of implementation has been added in the below code snippet) **:**

```js
const OriginalData = {
   Red:{
      Name:"L",
      List:[
         ["1", "5"],
         ["2", "5"],
         ["7", "9" ],
      ]
   },
   Blue:{
      Name:"BL",
      List:[
         ["1", "5"],
         ["7", "9" ],
         ["10", "13" ],
         ["15", "20"]
      ]
   }
};

Object.keys(OriginalData).forEach(key => {
  // Flatten the original array list. 
    OriginalData[key].List = OriginalData[key].List.flat()
  // Find min and max numbers from the array.
  const min = Math.min(...OriginalData[key].List);
  const max = Math.max(...OriginalData[key].List);
  // empty existing list array.
  OriginalData[key].List = [];
  // Now using for loop assign the values to the list array based on min and max value.
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    OriginalData[key].List.push(i);
  }
});

// Result
console.log(OriginalData);
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an array of all the numbers in a given range, you can create a new array with the required size and then map each of it's entries to the entry's index plus the given lower bound.

```
function fillRange(r) {
    let b = +r[1]
    let a = +r[0]
    if (a > b) {
        let tmp = a
        a = b
        b = tmp
    }
    return Array(b - a + 1).fill(0).map((e, i) => a + i)
}
```

This function flattens an array and removes all duplicate entries.

```
function union(arrays) {
    let flattened = [].concat.apply([], arrays)
    return flattened.reduce(
            (total, e) => {
                let i = total.indexOf(e)
                if (i === -1) {
                    total.push(e)
                }
                return total
            }, [])
}
```

Then this code produces the desired result from a list of ranges:

```
function unionRanges(ranges) {
    let expanded = ranges.map((e) => fillRange(e))
    return union(expanded).sort((a,b) => (a-b))
}
```

The final object can be created like this:

```
function processData(data) {
    let res = {}
    res.Level = {}
    res.Basement = {}
    res.Custom = {}
    
    res.Level.Name = data.Red.Name;
    res.Level.List = unionRanges(data.Red.List)
    
    res.Basement.Name = data.Blue.Name
    res.Basement.List = unionRanges(data.Blue.List)
    
    res.Custom.List = union(data.Black.List)
    
    return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flat the array, get the min and max and finally with a loop create the desired array.

```js
const array = [["1","5"],["7","9"],["10","13"],["15","20"]];         
const flatted = array.flat();
const min = Math.min(...flatted);
const max = Math.max(...flatted);

const result = Array.from({length: max + 1 - min}).map(function(_, i) {
    return i + min;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This just gives min and max of the flattened array. I need the min max of each array, and flatten the values

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas now it's up to you how to use it to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below codes help you.

```
const OriginalData = {
    Red: {
        Name: "L",
        List: [
            ["1", "5"],
            ["2", "5"],
            ["7", "9"],
        ]
    },
    Blue: {
        Name: "BL",
        List: [
            ["1", "5"],
            ["7", "9"],
            ["10", "13"],
            ["15", "20"]
        ]
    },
    Black: {
        List: [
            ["Random"],
            "Random2"
        ]
    }
};

//Iterating over the object OriginalData
Object.keys(OriginalData).forEach(key => {
    // Flatten the array "List" of each element
    OriginalData[key].List = OriginalData[key].List.flat();

    // Checking if the flatten array contains integers
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(OriginalData[key].List[0]))) {
        // Calculating the min and max of the "List" array
        const min = Math.min(...OriginalData[key].List);
        const max = Math.max(...OriginalData[key].List);

        let tmpArr = [];
        // Generating the array with numbers from min to max
        for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            tmpArr.push(i);
        }
        // Updating the original "List" (containing integers) of each element
        OriginalData[key].List = tmpArr;
    }
});

console.log(OriginalData);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).